# find specific element for button using selenium for web scraping

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I am inspecting one button element from a web page using chrome driver and selenium. And the html code for the particular button is:

```
<div class="label text-left text-link link-blue text- 
uppercase">Financial Statement Analysis <span class="count">(2)</span> 
</div>
```

I have tried different element options like find element by name, xpath, link text etc. But none of them unable to locate the element. 
What will be the element to locate the button. ?

Comment: what is the exception trace ? and update the question with tried locators.

Comment: try xpath '//div[contains(. , 'Financial Statement Analysis')]'

Comment: *I have tried different element options*... Which exactly? Share your code

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_ ? Why do you want to find the specific element?

Answer (score 0):

try Xpath :

```
//span[contains(@class,'count') and text() = '(2)']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this css selector :

```
div.label.text-left.text-link.link-blue.text-.uppercase
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element with text as **Financial Statement Analysis (2)** you can use the following solution:

- *Java* Solution:

  ```
  WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='label text-left text-link link-blue text-uppercase'][contains(.,'Financial Statement Analysis')]"));
  ```